# How can I make an element appear on top of a layout

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked many times. However all the answers I have tried to find have failed me. I want the textview to appear on top of the constraint layout but every time I try to run the application I just see the web view vidged which is connected to the constraint layout.

The last solution I tried was to reduce elevation of the layout to 1dp and increase elevation of the TextView to 2dp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:background="@drawable/green_border_background" android:elevation="1dp">


<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="top"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          android:elevation="2dp"
          android:id="@+id/textView2"
          tools:text="0"
          android:textSize="30sp"

/>
```

At the moment I do not care if the textview is centered, vertically below or vertically above the layout. I just want it to be visible. It is under the layout (Z vise) and thereby invisible. Elevation is the problem I am facing.

Comment: what do you mean you want it on top of a layout? There can be two kinds of top here, one meaning you want it as the first element, second meaning can be you want it to be like the view which is in front of all the views.

Comment: you have provided all constrain to parent which will make view to be centered.

Comment: Just set the vertical bias to 0 :D

Comment: Currently the textview is invisible as it is under the layout. I want i to be on top of the layout so that it can be visible.

Comment: @VaskoVasilev please edit your question to mention _elevation_ then. Most people are assuming top to refer to the _y_ position in the layout rather than _z_.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <TextView
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:text="Title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This code place the `TextView` on the top of the `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Please paste your full xml then I can help you

Comment: In my idea, it is at the top of all views

Answer (score 0):

Just check the [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

Read the "Adjust the constraint bias" part, try to set the

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
```